# Arduino interrupt-driven I2C communication with Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, linux, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am trying to allow a Raspberry Pi to access sensor data on an Arduino. My idea is:

1. Raspberry Pi requests for a set of data by writing something (irrelevant, ignored) to Arduino;
2. Arduino performs measurements, which involves precise timing (that is, extra I2C calls throws off timing and invalidates measurements)
3. After all results is gathered, Arduino sends out a high pulse over GPIO 8, which is received by Raspberry Pi as a low pulse on GPIO 7 (WiringPi numbering, an open collector inverter is used)
4. Raspberry Pi performs reading over I2C.

Now I am having issues transferring C structures over I2C. Can anyone tell me how?

Pi-side code is written in C.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked my source code and found a programming error. Sorry, please close.